# Why can't output '</script>' when using XslCompiledTransform to Transform .xml to .html

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I want to using `XslCompiledTransform` to transform the xml using xsl. But I find the script block was out put as `<script src="..."/>` not `<script src="..." ></script>`, how to make it right?

Even though my xsl file is as follow :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello iCore Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML both forms `<script ...></script>` and `<script ... />` are valid and equivalent.

To force the end tag add `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to stylesheet.

Comment: But i can browse the html in browser(IE,FF,Chrome).If not add `</script>` can browse the result. I don't know why

Comment: @huoxudong125 I suspect that you did not read Richard's answer. Both forms are valid and equivalent, both in xml and html. That is why you can 'browse the result'.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin `<xsl:output method="html"/>` there is no effect.I have tried it; I add `;` before `</script>` to solve the problem temporarily.